# Android: how to prevent data to be saved after rotation

Tags: android, rotation

I want to prevent a creation of a note object when the screen is rotated.
I know that a new activity is created after rotation, framework will save all the editable widgets data before destroying that activity.

I have a cancel button that works fine when I don't rotate the screen.
The outer else activiated when I rotate the screen.

```
   @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mIsCancelling) {
        if (mIsNewNote) {
            Log.d(TRACE_TAG, "onPause() : mIsCancelling == true && mIsNewNote == true => DataManager.removeNote(position:" + mNotePosition + ")");
            DataManager.getInstance().removeNote(mNotePosition);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TRACE_TAG, "onPause() : mIsCancelling == true && mIsNewNote == false => storePreviousNoteValues()");
            storePreviousNoteValues();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TRACE_TAG, "onPause() : mIsCancelling == false => saveNote()");
        saveNote();
    }
}

   @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.d(TRACE_TAG, "onSaveInstanceState(outState)");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(ORIGINAL_NOTE_COURSE_ID, mOriginalNoteCourseId);
    outState.putString(ORIGINAL_NOTE_TITLE, mOriginalNoteTitle);
    outState.putString(ORIGINAL_NOTE_TEXT, mOriginalNoteText);
}

private void restoreOriginalNoteValues(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TRACE_TAG, "restoreOriginalNoteValues(savedInstanceState)");
    mOriginalNoteCourseId = savedInstanceState.getString(ORIGINAL_NOTE_COURSE_ID);
    mOriginalNoteTitle = savedInstanceState.getString(ORIGINAL_NOTE_TITLE);
    mOriginalNoteText = savedInstanceState.getString(ORIGINAL_NOTE_TEXT);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSpinnerCourses = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_courses);

    List<CourseInfo> courses = DataManager.getInstance().getCourses();
    ArrayAdapter<CourseInfo> adapterCourses =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, courses);
    adapterCourses.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinnerCourses.setAdapter(adapterCourses);

    Log.d(TRACE_TAG, "OnCreate(savedInstanceState) => readDisplayStateValues()");
    readDisplayStateValues();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d(TRACE_TAG, "OnCreate(savedInstanceState) : savedInstanceState == null => saveOriginalNoteValues()");
        saveOriginalNoteValues();
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TRACE_TAG, "OnCreate(savedInstanceState) : savedInstanceState != null => restoreOriginalNoteValues(savedInstanceState)");
        restoreOriginalNoteValues(savedInstanceState);
    }

    mTextNoteTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_note_title);
    mTextNoteText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_note_text);

    if (!mIsNewNote) {
        Log.d(TRACE_TAG, "OnCreate(savedInstanceState) : mIsNewNote == false => displayNote(...)");
        displayNote(mSpinnerCourses, mTextNoteTitle, mTextNoteText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Activity tag of Manifest file you should have to mention

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

If you are using Android 2.3(API level 13 ) and above use

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

or you can override this method

```
 @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```